# Excel VBA Dim a new

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to vba coding and I'm getting hung up with how to navigate between sheets.  I have a workbook that contains a single sheet and that sheet is copied into a new workbook so that it can be edited without damaging the origianl.  The issue that I'm having is when the new work book is created I need to copy informaton from a 3rd workbook and paste it into the new one.  I've tried a number of things but haven't been able to figure it out.  I think the issue is that the new book doesn't have a name just Book# so once I leave to activate the other book I don't have a solid path back.

Sorry for the lack of an actual example.  I have added the first 2 lines based on the response I received.

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

' Open the 3rd workbook & copy
    Workbooks.Open ("Z:\Terms And Conditions.xlsx")
    Windows("Terms And Conditions.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 4")).Select
        Selection.Copy

' Return to wb and paste
    ActiveWorkbook(wb).Activate    'The code is stopping here
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A534").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: The workbook has a location (on disk) though, so you should be able to use [Workbook.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)

Comment: it's just wb.activate

Answer (score 1):

it would help to see some code but if you are simply copying the sheet to create a new workbook you can store a reference to the activeworkbook

```
dim wb as workbook
set wb = activeworkbook
```

and then refer to wb later in the code as required